# VBA Append Query Using Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am attempting to add a button to a form to add the contents of the form as a new line in my table.  I have written this line of code before, but this time it isn't working.

My form contains text and integers.  3 boxes on the form are auto-populated when the form loads. (Will the auto populated boxes change anything?)

Instead of trying to make the whole string work, I have reduced my code to just add one box (one of the auto-populated boxes).  I get a Rune-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

I've tried googling the error, but I cannot find anything that applies.

The code is as follows:

```
Dim strInsert As String

strInsert = "INSERT INTO NLog(IDKEY) " & _
    " Values(" & Me.TxtIdKey & ")"

Debug.Print strInsert
CurrentProject.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError


MsgBox ("Entry Added")
```

When I look at the debug screen it shows the following:
INSERT INTO NLog(IDKEY)  Values(OH08801405)

I am so frustrated! I am still very new to this, and I feel totally out of my element.

Comment: I'm guessing the error is on the line CurrentProject.Execute?  The error means that the object "CurrentProject" doesn't support the property or method "Execute".  I don't see anywhere you've made a database connection.  You need a connection object and a command object to execute a query.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you aren't using bound fields to do accomplish what you are trying to do?

Comment: That is the way I initially had my DB set up since it is a simple database.  Because I am autopopulating two of the fields in order to Append to the DB, I didn't think that bound would work.  My brother, who writes code for Wolfram, said that bound fields are bad, so I was also trying to get away from bound forms.

Comment: I think avoiding bound fields in MS Access is going to make your coding experience less than pleasant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could execute your `INSERT` statement with ADO like this ...

```vb
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strInsert
```

Note `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute`, not `CurrentProject.Execute`, and don't include the DAO constant *dbFailOnError* when executing from ADO.

Or with DAO like this ...

```
CurrentDb.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError
```

Also, you were attempting to insert a text value into the *IDKEY* field.  Assuming text is the correct datatype for that field, add quotes around the value you're inserting ...

```
strInsert = "INSERT INTO NLog(IDKEY) " & _
    " Values('" & Me.TxtIdKey & "')"
```

Then you should see `Debug.Print` output similar to this ...

```sql
INSERT INTO NLog(IDKEY) Values('OH08801405')
```

Without quotes surrounding *OH08801405*, the db engine will not understand it is supposed to be a string value it should insert, and instead will assume it is a parameter for which you haven't supplied a value.

Comment: I don't even know why I try, I spot 2 things and you spot 8 Haha.  Apparently I need to hone my powers of observation.   Didn't even catch the non-numerical values in that IDKey, I just saw ID and assumed it was numerical.

Comment: Well I spotted the missing quotes right off, but that didn't account for the error message Sarah reported.  It took me longer to realize `CurrentProject.Execute` was the cause of the first error.  And the quote issue was waiting to trip her up after the first error was fixed.  :-)

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be working now! Just adding one field at a time since I stink at "' or ".  When I am inserting a date... do I use " or '"?

Comment: Include `#` characters to delimit Date/Time values ... `#2015-01-16#`.  If prefer to use *yyyy-mm-dd* for Date/Time to avoid any possible confusion over whether the date is *dd/mm/yyyy* or *mm/dd/yyyy*.

Comment: Now I am getting a syntax error. Here is what I have:  '" & Me.NoticeReason & "','" & #Me.DateRec# & "','" & #Me.DateNotice# & "')"

Comment: The `#` should be inside quotes ... instead of  `"','" & #Me.DateRec# & "','"` ... use `"',#" & Me.DateRec & "#,'"`

Answer (score 1):

I have to assume that the error message is happening at `CurrentProject.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError` since your debug actually shows something.

You will need to set up a connection to your database and use `db.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError`.

You declare a connection like this:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
```

So you should end up with something like:

```
Dim strInsert As String
Dim db As DAO.Database

strInsert = "INSERT INTO NLog(IDKEY) " & _
            " Values(" & Me.TxtIdKey & ")"

Debug.Print strInsert

Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError


MsgBox ("Entry Added")
```

Comment: Well that did something!  Now I am getting a Rune Time error '3061': Too few parameters. Expected 1.

Comment: Can you post your debug line again?  Edit: Just ignore my answer and go with HansUp :)